# how do i replace variables into a string in js

Tags: javascript

I have something like this:

```
let param1 = 'nice';
let param2 = 'awesome';
let product = `awesome/${param1}/restaurants/${param2}`;
```

The thing is in `product` variable, i don't know where i would have dynamic variables such as `param1` and `param2`. it could be both in the end, or in the beginning or as it is right now or any other case.

How do I replace `param1` and `param2` with `nice` and `awesome` dynamically?

Comment: `"awesome/{param1}/restaurants/{param2}".replace("{param1}", param1).replace("{param2}", param2); ` ??

Comment: The way you show: template strings literally do that thing, and if you paste your code in the dev console, that's exactly what it does. Just form your final string when you _do_ know that you have both parameters, and you're good to go, and if necessary, have fallback defaults available (e.g. `blah/${thing || DEFAULT_CATEGORY}/blah`)

Answer (score 2):

Not 100% clear on what you're asking, because your example code seems like exactly what you want. It doesn't matter how the values of `param1` and `param2` are defined; the template string you have is how to include variables in a string. Depending on how/when those variables are defined, you might want to verify that they are not `undefined`, and that they are of type `string`, before using them.

Edited to add:

@NikaKurashvili Maybe start with the string you're building (a url path?), identify the parts that can change, and make each of those parts a variable that is included in the template string.

If the string you're building can have an arbitrary # of parts (this would be unusual for a URL), you would have to approach it differently. You would likely want to store the variable values in an array or an object, and iterate through them to build the URL. Since the order/position of the variables within the string is likely important, the way you store the variables would have to reflect that order/position. If this is the case, an example/more detail would help us understand how best to approach it.

Comment: I won't know how many dynamic variables will be there in that string and where they will be placed. :) this example is fine, but what if i got 5 dynamic variables in there without knowing it?

Comment: @NikaKurashvili  My suggestion would be to give a worst case example of "what if" in your original post.  We're clear on the two variables being there, but you're not being clear on *but what if i got 5 dynamic variables in there without knowing it*  --  Can you demonstrate what this would at least look like?